# MySQL: split field, do string replace and concat on each part, then rejoin

Tags: mysql, regex, split

I have a text field in a database which stores multiple email addresses, separated by a mixture of spaces, commas and semicolons (the appearance of these is pretty random as it's user-entered data).  I need to change each email address in this string so that i change the "@" to ".at." and then put "@fake.mydomain.com" at the end, then rejoin them with ", ", ie comma-space.

So, for example, I want to go from this

```
"michael.dolenz@gmail.com, daveyjones@hotmail.co.uk;mike.nesmith.1@foo.com;,petertork@mymail.com"
```

to this

```
"michael.dolenz.at.gmail.com@fake.mydomain.com, daveyjones.at.hotmail.co.uk@fake.mydomain.com, mike.nesmith.1.at.foo.com@fake.mydomain.com, petertork.at.mymail.com@fake.mydomain.com"
```

For the sake of examples, the table is called `campaigns` and the field is called `email_addresses`.

If the field was just a single email address i can do it with

```
update campaigns set email_addresses = concat(replace(email_addresses,'@', '.at.'), '@fake.mydomain.com'
```

so i guess i need to do "split on regex like /[\s,;]+/", do the above to each part, and then join with ", ".

Can i do this with a single mysql command? 
thanks, Max

EDIT: in the version of MySQL on our server, i cannot do regex-based REPLACE, otherwise i would use something like REPLACE(email_addresses, '/[,;\s^]+/', '@fake.mydomain.com, ')

Comment: Why do you need to split and rejoin the strings? Would a simple [string replace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) suffice?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins yes it would, i assumed that there would be splitting involved but if there's a way to do it without then that's great.

Answer (score 0):

The example text looks like you have a semi-colon in there that looks like a delimiter. I'm assuming your example should have all commas as the delimiters, per your description.

Try this:

```
select concat(replace(replace('michael.dolenz@gmail.com, daveyjones@hotmail.co.uk,mike.nesmith.1@foo.com,petertork@mymail.com','@','.at.'),',','@fake.mydomain.com,'),'@fake.mydomain.com');
```

Output looks like this:

michael.dolenz.at.gmail.com@fake.mydomain.com, daveyjones.at.hotmail.co.uk@fake.mydomain.com,mike.nesmith.1.at.foo.com@fake.mydomain.com,petertork.at.mymail.com@fake.mydomain.com

Basically, replace the '@' with '.at.', replace the comma with '@fake.mydomain.com', and add @fake.mydomain.com to the end for the last field that doesn't have a comma delimiter.

Comment: Thanks Jamie.  Like i said, the input is user generated and can contain semicolons.  I want to replace any combination of space, comma and semicolon with `", "` in the output.

Comment: Can add another replace to swap the semicolons with blanks, and you can trim the data to remove superfluous spaces.